# Show content based on whether the user has certain tag in Mailchimp

Tags: conditional-statements, html-email, mailchimp

I went through the Merge Tags [here](https://mailchimp.com/help/all-the-merge-tags-cheat-sheet/#Conditional_Block_Tags) and [here](https://mailchimp.com/help/use-conditional-merge-tag-blocks/), but couldn't figure out the syntax that would allow me to show content based on whether the user has certain [Tag](https://mailchimp.com/help/getting-started-tags/) or not.

Help?

---

My goal in case it helps:

User subscribes, and is queued for a welcome mail one day later. In meantime that user may get tagged (my way of segmenting them), and so, the next day when that user receives the welcome mail, the content needs to be catered based on the tag that user got.

Answer (score 3):

Got a response from their support saying

> merge tags do not work with Tags just yet

here's the whole thing:

> While we do have conditional merge tags available, I'm afraid we do
>   not have any that would work with Tags. To be transparent, Tags were
>   recently added a few months ago, and there are some features in our
>   application that has not updated to work with Tags just yet.
>
> Because conditional merge tags do not work with tags yet, the best
>   option would be to create multiple automations and send them out based
>   on each tags. If you do it that way, you'll be able to target those in
>   specific tags with specific content

Comment: In your last comment u we're after user tags. Maybe good to update the answer to say user tags?

Comment: Any update from their support on when this feature might be coming?

Comment: @Boris nope.  Nothing of a kind

Answer (score 0):

Dug a little deeper from the first link. There is another link *Use Conditional Merge Tag Blocks* which contained the below code:

**Name**
*IF-ELSE*

**Definition**

Use ELSE to indicate alternative content to display if the `*|MERGE|*` tag value is false.

**Example**

```
*|IF:MERGE|* content to display *|ELSE:|* alternative content to display *|END:IF|*
```

**Name**
*ELSEIF*

**Definition**

Use ELSEIF to specify a new `*|MERGE|*` tag to be matched against if the first `*|MERGE|*` tag value is false.

**Example**

```
*|IF:TRANSACTIONS >= 20|* Enjoy this 40% off coupon! *|COUPON40|* 
*|ELSEIF:TRANSACTIONS >= 10|* Enjoy this 20% off coupon! *|COUPON20|* 
*|ELSE:|* Enjoy this 10% off coupon! *|COUPON10|* *|END:IF|*
```

More examples with definitions can be found [here](https://mailchimp.com/help/use-conditional-merge-tag-blocks/).

Hope this is the answer you were after.

Comment: No, that's not it. While this explains how to use Merge Tags to make decisions based on list fields, it doesn't show how to make decisions based on [user tags](https://mailchimp.com/help/getting-started-tags/).

Comment: Can you update your question to add more details then please? What i got from your question `the syntax that would allow me to show content based on whether the user has certain tag or not`, you have a field populated, wouldnt it be an if else?

Comment: Of course it should be an if/else, but it turns out that user tags are not supported. Just got response from their support team.

Comment: @Birowsky can you add that as an answer and mark it as correct? Specifically: tags are not supported, with a quote from their support team? // ...What also might be useful for you is their "group" feature. That allows you to set "preferences" and you can have dynamic content based on them.